# data_arr = pickle.loads(data) EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, pickle, send

When my server receives the pickle.dumps data and loads it pickle.loads (data) it generates the following error

data_arr = pickle.loads (data)
EOFError: Entry timed out

```
import socket
import pickle

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(4096)
    data_arr = pickle.loads(data)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: The first call to `.recv(4096)` obviously did not receive the entire pickle.  You need to accumulate the data, and only call `.loads()` on it once you have the whole thing.

Comment: Adding to he comment above. If you are using streams there is no easy way to tell where one message ends and another one starts. You may add some kind of separator between messages or a header with the size of the object in bytes. Depending on the case you may consider using a messaging framework like ZMQ